# stale element reference element is not attached to the page document when trying to scrape information from different links

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, staleelementreferenceexception

I am using Selenium on Python and trying to move the cursor and click on a specific element. This works for the first link and the structure of the HTML is the same for the next link but I get a StaleElementReferenceException for the second link when accessing it through the same webdriver. Why does this happen and how do I fix it? Below is the code I am running. Thank you so much!

```
def getZest(url):
    zestlist = []
    yearlist = []
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    
    
    result = False;
    attempts = 0;
    while(attempts < 5):
        try:
            Home_Value = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Home value']")))
            action.move_to_element(Home_Value).click().perform()
    
            zestimate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ds-home-values"]/div/div[3]/button')
            action.move_to_element(zestimate).perform()
            result = True
            break
        except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException as e:
            print(e)
        attempts = attempts + 1
fivenums = ["https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/212-Haddrell-St-Mount-Pleasant-SC-29464/10922911_zpid/", "https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/20-Grove-St-Hicksville-NY-11801/31127407_zpid/"]
for num in fivenums:
    getZest(num)
```

Comment: @DebanjanB I realize that you have a lot of experience with Selenium, if you could help out that would be great!

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DebanjanB I am trying to click on an element on a website for multiple links in the same webdriver. However, when the webdriver moves onto the second link, I get an StaleElementReferenceException. This is the case for whatever link it is that I am trying to access. I want to get rid of this Exception and be able to click on the element on the website for all the links in the list. Thanks for the help and I will change the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get informations about the first and second link with the following code, without any error:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.common import exceptions

u = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/moving-margins/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()

def getZest(url):
    zestlist = []
    yearlist = []
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    
    
    result = False
    attempts = 0
    action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 300)
    while(attempts < 5):
        try:
            Home_Value = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Home value']")))
            action.move_to_element(Home_Value).click().perform()
    
            zestimate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ds-home-values"]/div/div[3]/button')
            action.move_to_element(zestimate).perform()
            result = True
            break
        except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException as e:
            print(e)
        attempts = attempts + 1
fivenums = ["https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/212-Haddrell-St-Mount-Pleasant-SC-29464/10922911_zpid/", "https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/20-Grove-St-Hicksville-NY-11801/31127407_zpid/"]
for num in fivenums:
    getZest(num)
```

In your code there it's not showed where some variables are instantiated so, maybe this is were the problem is located.

However when opening the first link, the website showed me the Google Captcha protection, so, I suppose you have some kind of authorization to scrape the informations with the permission of the owner.